# vuejs adds always # in the URL

Tags: vue.js, fullpage.js

im using VueJS and FullpageJS for my website.
Somehow the website adds always an anchor like this:

I enter asdf at the end of the URL and instead of the 404 page I get the landingpage with an added #.

I already checked the whole code if i did any obvious mistakes, which I didnt.

Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Fws.png) will be [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sVBn.png).

router.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Landingpage from '@/components/Landingpage';
import Terms from '@/components/Terms';
import LegalNotice from '@/components/LegalNotice';
import Errorpage from '@/components/Error'
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Landingpage',
            component: Landingpage
        },
        {
            path: '/terms',
            name: 'Terms',
            component: Terms
        },
        {
            path: '/legal',
            name: 'LegalNotice',
            component: LegalNotice
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            name: 'Error',
            component: Errorpage
        }
    ]
})
```

I appreciate any idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) if you don’t want a # in the url